# Is there a way of setting a different footer size on the last page of a word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

Using Microsfot Word 2013:

Is there a way of setting **a different footer size** on **the last page** of a document?

So far I have only found ways of having different footer contents, but nothing on different footer sizes.

`EDIT` It is important for the solution to be ***template-friendly***, so that the user will not have to go through the same process for every document.

Comment: page setup can be different at section level, so if your last page always have same / similar content, then adding a section break before it and changing footer might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I managed to do so far:

1. Go to the last page.
2. Select `Page Layout` > `Page Setup`.

   [image]
3. Select the `Layout` tab, then select `Apply to:` `This point forward`.

   [image]
4. Change the edge, select `Section start:` `Continuous`, and click `OK`.

This is only ***in part*** satisfying, because it requires some manual handling (i.e. it is not template-friendly).